# optional character in Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, validation, date

I've found this REGEXP:

```
^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

It's useful to validate a date in this format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

with "-" as separator. It's perfect for me except that I'd like to make this:

```
1970-1-1
```

valid too, so I'm looking for a modification to have the zero optional in month and day block as first char. Could you please provide me some help?

Comment: Explain a little bit more, you want to be able to validate 1997-4-5 too?

Comment: Yeah, not just the example any combination of month/day that use a single char each (except 0). So yyyy - from 1 to 9 - from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an optional zero, you can this RegEx (edited version of your own):

```
^[0-9]{4}-((?:0)?[1-9]|1[0-2])-((?:0)?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

To make a character ( or a range) optional in RegEx, put it in a parenthesis followed by a question mark:

`[a-z]` is mandatory

`([a-z])?` is optional, with capturing group

`(?:[a-z])?` without capturing group, just optional

[Read more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) on Capturing group in RegEx

Comment: So basically, what's the advantage of using non capturing group instead of the solution proposed by npinti?

Comment: I don't know. I do not see any optional character in his method. But about capturing and non-capturing, I should say, non-capturing groups actually utilize parenthesis only for visual grouping (you see them better), this still keeps your return value clean. While if you want to group your RegEx into parenthesis, without non-capturing groups there will be many captures just unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like so: `^[0-9]{4}-(([1-9])|(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))-(([1-9])|(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))$`.

An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/oV6bD3/1).

Answer (score 1):

Use your current regex just make the `0` optional `0?`

```
^[0-9]{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

---

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bU8lO5/1)

Answer (score 0):

PHP already has a construct to extract dates; if you're using a regex to extract the date instead, ["Now you have two problems"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/98845)

PHP's [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php): "Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format"

You can use it's `d` or `j` option to accept 1 or 2 digit days and it's `m` or `n` option to accept 1 or 2 digit months.

The format you'll want to use is: `"Y-m-d"`